# MySQL table creation error 1064 - can't find reason

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table in a MySQL database that has three foreign keys, but am getting an error.  This error is not obvious to me, and can use a third party check.

```
CREATE TABLE `main_message`(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  strat_key INT NULL,
  task INT NULL,
  user INT,
  comment VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  datestamp DATETIME, 
  FOREIGN KEY strat_key REFERENCES prod_main_strategicdirection(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY task REFERENCES main_task(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY user REFERENCES prod_auth_user(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

According to the output, I'm getting the error message

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' foreign key strat_key
references prod_main_strategicdirection(id) on update cas'
```

just after the first foreign key declaration

```
FOREIGN KEY strat_key REFERENCES prod_main_strategicdirection(id)
```

but I see nothing obvious to what would be causing the error.

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: Added error message, but MYSQL error 1064 messages are pretty generic and just give locations, which I detailed in the original posting.

Comment: But you are not using MySQL (you are using a FORK of MySQL -> MariaDB) are you sure that you can use INNODB on that?

Comment: Its mostly a drop in replacement

Comment: yes, innodb is fully compliant with mariadb/mysql\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**You forgot the parenthesis on the `FOREIGN KEY` and to remove the comma after the last `CASCADE` before the closing `)`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

```
CREATE TABLE `main_message`(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  strat_key INT NULL,
  task INT NULL,
  user INT,
  comment VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  datestamp DATETIME, 
  FOREIGN KEY(strat_key) REFERENCES prod_main_strategicdirection(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(task) REFERENCES main_task(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES prod_auth_user(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

**[Live DEMO.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9474a)**

**[Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)**

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
    RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
```